# Finding old versions of iOS apps (for 5.1.1 on a 1st Generation iPad)

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I have a first generation iPad that was working perfectly well, 
and was loaded with apps which worked perfectly well. For various reasons I did a factory reset.

Now I can't reinstall many of the old apps, because they require iOS 6.0.
Is there a way to find and install old versions of Apple App Store Apps?  The YELP and PBS apps are examples.

---

Related questions include:
* [How to install apps which require a newer version of iOS on a 1st gen. iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/how-to-install-apps-which-require-ios-6-on-a-1st-gen-ipad)
* [How do I upgrade my iOS on my iPad 1st generation?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130758/how-do-i-upgrade-my-ios-on-my-ipad-1st-generation)

Comment: @Fiksdal This is not a duplicate as this question wants the old apps whilst the other asks how to install apps that need a new OS

Comment: @Mark Fair enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

my daughter showed me an easy way to install the older Apple store apps. you simply log onto the apple store using a computer (without the iPad connected). find & download the software to the library on that computer. once it is added to your library, goto the app store on the iPad & install the software...
since the newest version won't work for the iPad, it will ask you if you would like to install the latest compatible version.
this seems to work for 85% of the apps out there (as long as there was a prior compatible version). 
:)

Comment: This does not work for Google (Docs, Sheets, Drive) or Apple (Pages, Numbers, Keynote) Any suggestions for those?

Comment: @Maclibrarian Ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

You may find some of your old Apps on the Mac/PC your iPad was synchronized with before you did the factory reset. Your Apps may be in the Mobile Applications or Trash folder. You can reinstall files with the ending ".ipa" by dragging them into iTunes. If you have a backup of your Mac/PC you should find your old Apps there.