# Install old app versions on iOS 5.1.1

Tags: itunes, ipad, applications, ios

A friend of mine discovered an old iPad 1 at his grandfathers house. This iPad has never been used before and we both tried to activate it and install apps.
Activation worked fine and even the update to the latest available iOS 5.1.1 worked flawlessly (coming from iOS 3 ! ;-))

But now we have problems installing any apps. I know there are "cheats" to make an iPad install retained older versions of an app (if they are still provided by the developer).

But regardless of which approaches we try, we always receive the error message "`This application requires iOS 7`" (translated from German) and are not asked if we want to install an older version.
There are the links to the recipes we found on Stack Exchange:

- [Finding old versions of iOS apps (for 5.1.1 on a 1st Generation iPad)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141840/finding-old-versions-of-ios-apps-for-5-1-1-on-a-1st-generation-ipad)
- [How to install apps which require a newer version of iOS on a 1st gen. iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/how-to-install-apps-which-require-ios-6-on-a-1st-gen-ipad)

Basically all of these approaches involve "claiming" the app on iTunes and later installing it on the iPad using the cloud download button while automatic downloads are disabled.
The strange thing is that I myself own an iPad 1 on which I updated all apps regularly starting in 2010. I am able to run apps on my iPad but can't install the same on the iPad of my friend.

Unfortunately my friend wants to install different apps than I have, so we can't simply take the installer files from a backup of my iPad 1.

What else can I try to get the apps on that iPad ? I use iTunes 12.3.1.23 x64 on Windows and iOS 5.1.1, perhaps this is a combination on which the "cheat" does no longer work.

Comment: You must purchase the app using a compatible device (or iTunes) with the same Apple ID before downloading an app to an older devices.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thanks for your input, but this is basically what I did: I selected the app on iTunes and tried to "downgrade" it on the iPad. Using a compatible device is not feasible because that would mean I need to use my friends ID on my iPad 3 (my second and last iOS device)

Comment: If you download the app to iTunes using the same Apple ID, then you can download it to the iPad. You may need to go to Updates > Purchased on the App Store app to download it.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Yes, this is where I get the denial ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... That's odd. Maybe the app was never made for iOS 5 (i.e. The developer started developing it for iOS 6 and later)

Comment: @IronCraftMan Indeed ... But I tried with "Subway Surfer", which is (as an old version) running fine on my iPad 5. But in that iPad the Subway Surfer was first installed when iOS was the current version and received all the updates since then. Perhaps the old version was provided in by the developer in the past years but no more in 2015 ?!?

Comment: the developer doesn't control the version available, Apple does. They allow you to re-download previously purchased app. Unfortunately I don't know what else I can tell you to do. It works fine for me, using iOS 6. So if you have an iPad Air, why do you need this first gen iPad to work?

Comment: @IronCraftMan I thought a developer is allowed to revoke older versions of his application. The iPad is not mine, it is that of a friend. He found this unused iPad 1 (64 GB with UMTS, what a shame !) and the two of us wanted to revive it. Because I own an iPad1 (used by my kids) and an iPad3 (mine) we thought we can do like me and prepare his iPad1 for his kids.

Comment: No, the app is controlled by Apple. Now you have an iPad 3? Since its his iPad, and he bought the app with his Apple ID, he should be able to download it. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install apps which require iOS 6 on a 1st gen. iPad?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135060/how-to-install-apps-which-require-ios-6-on-a-1st-gen-ipad)